# Listen in application for insertion in database table

Tags: c#, sql, .net, events, triggers

I have a SQL Server 2005 database which registers events from some device in one table. I need to catch these events, as they occur, in my C# application.

Events can occur at any time. I'm looking for a good practice on how to manage database listening / catching something that database sends. There were some topics at stackoverflow about these problem but there was not one way which is recommended on these situations but only some not systematic advices on how it could be done.

So I ask about good practice. How these work should be done? Please, help.

In my opinion trigger which could send some information from table to c# application seems to be the best solution, only I do not know if it is possible to arrange trigger to do these work.

I will be grateful for any sugestion ;)

Comment: What kind of c# application? web wpf winforms?

Comment: Desktop app. C# + WPF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I know to be notified in C# by changes on a SQL table is by using [SqlDependencies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Example :

```
private async Task RegisterSqlDependency()
    {
        if (_dependency != null)
            _dependency.OnChange -= this.OnChange;
        String query = "select MyCol from dbo.MyTable WHERE myKey = '" + _dependecyKey + "'";

        using (SqlConnection connexion = new SqlConnection("ConnexionString"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connexion))
            {
                _dependency = new SqlDependency(command, null, 0);
                _dependency.OnChange += this.OnChange;
                await connexion.OpenAsync();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                       .... GetData ....
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

private void OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
      .... Data has changed on table ....
      call RegisterSqlDependency() again
    }
```

You'll have to enable SERVICE BROKER on your database to enable SqlDepedency with this :

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET ENABLE_BROKER with rollback immediate;
```

Comment: @sloth, U know better way?

Comment: @DawidJablonski Another way? Yes. A better way? No.